# How to update UI first in a function in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a function called myAction when I performing it will takes a lot of time. 
So, How to update textFiled first in myAction function?

```
func doAction() {

    //  do this action will take a lot of time
}

@IBAction func myAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    // update textField first
    self.textFild?.stringValue = "start do action!"

    doAction()

    // update textField when doAction finished
    self.textFild?.stringValue = "finished action!"
}
```

Comment: DoAction() before complete // update textfield complete ?

Comment: I need to update textField UI fist and then do "doAction" function, finally update textField UI.

Answer (score 0):

A better of doing this is using a completion handler in your `doAction()` and then once it is completed, you can update the your `textField` to `"finished action"`. Set the `"start do action!"` in `viewDidLoad()` itself so that the textField reads `"start do action!"` as soon as the view finishes loading, like so:

```
class someClass: ... {

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
self.textField?.text = "start do action"
//your code
}

func doAction(completion: (finished: Bool) -> ()){

//your code
completion(finished: true)

}

@IBAction func myAction(sender: AnyObject) {

doAction{success in

if success{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
 self.textField?.text = "finished action!"     //Update on main thread
}) 
}
else{
//do something else
}

}
}
```

This should work. Try it :)

Comment: Dershowitz123 thanks, but it is not inside of NSViewController